# Having Object value but react says undefined react redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

```
const orderId = props.match.params.id;

const orderDetails = useSelector((state) => state.orderDetails);
const { loading, error, order } = orderDetails;
const dispatch = useDispatch();
const toPrice = (num) => Number(num.toFixed(2));
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(detailsOrder(orderId));
}, [dispatch, orderId]);
return loading ? (
  <LoadingBox></LoadingBox>
  ) : error ? (
  <MessageBox variant="danger"></MessageBox>
  ) : (
  <div>
    <div>
      <h2>Order ID: {order._id}</h2>
      <h4>{order.shippingAddress.city}</h4>
    </div>
  </div>
 );
```

When I display id only , there is no issue . Its displays fine. But When I use shippingAddress object it throws an error , " city is undefined " and also action is also not dispatched. But I have shippingAddress object with elements in redux store when I display id only.
Action Creator is:

```
export const detailsOrder = (orderId) => async (dispatch, getState) => {
  dispatch({ type: ORDER_DETAILS_REQUEST, payload: orderId });
  try {
    const {
      userSignin: { userInfo },
    } = getState();
    const { data } = await Axios.get(`/api/orders/${orderId}`, {
      headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${userInfo.token}` },
    });
   dispatch({ type: ORDER_DETAILS_SUCCESS, payload: data });
 } catch (error) {
   dispatch({
     type: ORDER_DETAILS_FAIL,
     payload:
       error.response && error.response.data.message
        ? error.response.data.message
        : error.message,
   });
 }
};
```

Reducer is:

```
export const orderDetailsReducer = (state = { order: [] }, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ORDER_DETAILS_REQUEST:
      return { loading: true };
    case ORDER_DETAILS_SUCCESS:
      return { loading: false, order: action.payload };
    case ORDER_DETAILS_FAIL:
      return { loading: false, error: action.payload };
    default:
      return state;
   }
 };
```

API call response is like that:

```
orderDetails:{
  order:{
      "shippingAddress": {
         "fullName": "Sowmiya Pachiappan",
         "address": "xxxx",
         "city": "xxxx",
         "postalCode": "xxxxx",
         "country": "xxxx"
      },
      "isPaid": false,
      "isDelivered": false,
      "_id": "6045ca2feca0270cf433162a", 
      "orderItems": [
         {
            "_id": "6045ca2feca0270cf433162b",    
            "product": "6042002e7cd2060fe4c59227",
            "qty": 5
         } 
       ],
      "paymentMethod": "Pay on Delivery",
      "itemsPrice": 250, 
      "shippingPrice": 0, 
      "totalTaxPrice": 12.5,
      "totalPrice": 272.5, 
      "user":"5ff2aae21a184c0b00b59637",  
      "status": "Order Placed",
      "createdAt": "2021-03-08T06:54:39.481Z",
      "updatedAt": "2021-03-08T06:54:39.481Z",
      "__v": 0
     }
   }
```

Comment: Is the error that "city is undefined" or is it rather something like "cannot access city **of** undefined", implying that `order.shippingAddress` is undefined? The latter makes more sense IMO. Can you include your `orderDetails`  reducer code and `detailsOrder` action creator?

Comment: Error is : TypeError: Cannot read property 'city' of undefined

Comment: Your initial state is `{ order: [] }` and as an array it likely won't ever have an `_id` or `shippingAddress` "property". Does `action.payload` mutate the state invariant in the SUCCESS/FAIL cases? What is the response shape? It looks like `state.orderDetails` changes from an array to an object.

Comment: when I print shippingaddress object in console It gives output like this:                                                address: "xxx"
city: "xxxx"
country: "xxx"
fullName: "xxxx"
postalCode: "xxxx"

Comment: If I use direct properties of the  "order" object, it does not throw any error. If I try to access nested object i.e. "order.shippingAddress" object, it throws error

Comment: Now It works when I give conditional rendering: order && order.shippingAddress && order.shippingAddress.fullName..... But it does not work if I give order && order.shippingAddress.fullname..I don't know why it happens like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Issue

The basic issue is that your initial state doesn't match what you attempt to access on the initial render cycle when you dispatch an action to presumably populate the state.

The initial reducer state is `{ order: [] }`. Initially `order` is an array, but you later update `order` to be an object.

`useSelector((state) => state.orderDetails)` provides you a valid, truthy `orderDetails` object, so accessing any property from this is ok.

```
orderDetails.order.shippingAddress // no error, value undefined
```

But when accessing deeper will throw the error you see

```
orderDetails.order.shippingAddress.city // error, can't access city of undefined
```

## Solution

Provide valid initial reducer state. Here you will want to provide at least a property for anything that is accessed on the initial render before state it populated/updated.

```
const initialState = {
  error: null,
  loading: false,
  order: {
    shippingAddress: {},
  },
};

const orderDetailsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => { ..... }
```

This will allow your initial render to work as now `orderDetails.data.shippingAddress` will be defined.

The alternative would be to use null-checks to guard against undefined accesses. A null-check is required ***at each level*** of depth into an object.

You can use guard clauses:

```
order && order.shippingAddress && order.shippingAddress.city
```

Or you can use [Optional Chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining):

```
order?.shippingAddress?.city
```